# Finding JSON POST format of an API

Tags: python, json, django, api

I'm trying to figure out the format to post data to an old undocumented API built with django python.

The API using the following code to extract the POST:

```
ids = json.loads(request.POST.get("data", "[]"))
```

The `ids` is a array of ints

The following script works to post to the API:

```
  data = dict(data="[1,3]")                                                               
  r = requests.post("http://apiurl", auth=("user", "pass"), data=data)
```

The following doesn't work:

```
data = dict(data="[1,3]")
data = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.post("http://apiurl", auth=("user", "pass"), data=data)
```

How would I figure out the json a third party would need to post to this API to use it?

Comment: Where's this api? Is it your own app? What are the responses when you do a HEAD or OPTIONS request to the api?

Comment: This is my own API, it was written by another developer. The HEAD and OPTIONS both give a 200.

Comment: @gmccoy: You'll have to look at the code. Unless you know something about the API, treating it like a black box probably won't get you very far.

Comment: @gmccoy: That's the http status. What's in the response body? And since you have the server side code for the api, everything you need to know can be found by reading it. If you can't figure it out, post a question here, but it's essetial to include the relevant source code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In[2]: import json
In[3]: data = dict(data="[1,3]")
In[4]: data
Out[4]: {'data': '[1,3]'}
In[5]: json.dumps(data)
Out[5]: '{"data": "[1,3]"}'
```

json.dumps(data) returns string.

From [requests doc](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py)

> :param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send
>   in the body of the :class:`Request`.

So API you use handle correctly post request with json:

```
{"data": "[list of ints]"}
#e.g.
{"data": "[2,3,4,5]"}
```

and that's you can figure out the third party.

Comment: Thanks, I did just have the syntax of what the JSON would be mixed up.